# How to run testcases in frameworks/base/core/tests/coretests

Tags: android, android-testing, android-cts

I want to run some of the testcases inside frameworks/base/core/tests/coretests. For example, I want to run "VirtualDisplayTest" in frameworks/base/core/tests/coretests/src/android/hardware/display/ . I want to run them on my nexus 10 tablet (kitkat). Plese suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Individual tests (or methods within those tests) can be run from CTS.

From your host, with the device connected via adb (assuming you have CTS downloaded etc.)

./cts-tradefed

> run cts -c android.display.cts.DisplayTest

or

> run cts -c android.display.cts.DisplayTest -m testGetCurrentSizeRange

(see help run within cts)